I would like to calculate the lifting force required to stand up my motorcycle after laying it down on its side (real life scenario after a crash)

What would be the formula used to calculate the force required to lift a fallen motorcycle (assume a uniform mass...no lever effect) that weighs say 550 lbs?  The answer is obviously angle-dependent...the more the motorcycle is lifted/rotated toward vertical, the less force required.  Is this as simple as taking the sine of the angle of rotation (90 deg. being laying flat on the ground, and 0 deg. being fully vertical) and multiplying it by the weight of the motorcycle divided by 2 (divided by 2 to assume a centrally located center of gravity)?

You say no lever effect yet this object is indeed a lever with gravity acting from its center of mass while your force is applied at the end.

No numbers but technique shown for a heavy motorbike.

A lot depends on the technique you use. The correct techniques of turning th handle bars as you rotate the bike to the upright position takes a lot less effort.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-V-kw2zUkSI&t=73s

For me, it was a real life scenario after letting it fall over.
Imagine the bike is laying on its side. One your friend is holding up the wheels and you are holding up the handlebars. Between the two of you, you are holding up the bike.
A bike has a low center of gravity. That means more mass is near the wheels than the handlebars. This is good for you and bad for your friend. He is holding up more weight. You need to know where the center of mass is to calculate how much.
In this case, the ground is your friend. To lift it upright, you have to lift just a little more than enough to hold it still. This will accelerate the handlebars upward.

When the bike is $\theta = 20^\circ$ to the ground, the component of the weight that is orthogonal to the frame height is $\cos(\theta)\times 550 = 541 \ \text{pounds-force}$. This causes a torque of $541 \times 2 = 1082 \ \text{foot-pounds force}$ around the contact point with the ground because the centre of gravity is two feet away from the contact point. You need to apply at least this much torque to lift the bike. You have already worked out that there is a mechanical advantage of $2$ due to the handlebars being twice as far from the contact point as the centre of gravity. This means you have to apply a force at least equal to
$$\frac{\text{torque}}{\text{distance from pivot}} = \frac{1082}{4} = 270.5 \ \text{pounds-force}$$ orthogonal to the frame height (preferably using your legs as shown in the videos).

What would be the formula used to calculate the force required to lift
a fallen motorcycle?

If $Mg$ is the weight of the motorcycle, the height of the motorcycle is $h$, the height of the centre of gravity is $x$, and the bike is initially leaning at an angle of $\theta$ from the floor, a single formula for the orthogonal force you have to apply is:  $$F = \cos (\theta) \times Mg \times \frac{x}{h}.$$

This is a problem made for torque, since it's about rotating the bike around a fixed point, where it touches the ground.
The weight of the motorcycle W affects a torque equal to Lw=W x Sc x sin(theta), where Sc is the distance from the point where the motorcycle touches the ground to its center of mass, and theta is the angle from the vertical (70 degrees in your case). If you push perpendicularly to the normally vertical axis of the motorcycle, at a distance Sy from the point it touches the ground (4' in your case) with a force Fy, the torque you exert is Ly=F x Sy.  You lift the motorcycle when Ly > Lw, or when F > W x (Sc/Sy) x sin(theta).
Let's say the center of mass of the bike is 1.5' from where it touches the ground.  Then the force you need as you've drawn it is F=550 lbs x 1.5'/4' x sin(70deg) = 194 lbs.
